# Display alert if checkbox isn't checked on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, alert

How I can issue a pop up alert, such that when a user clicks a button, and a checkbox isn't checked, an alert will appear using jQuery?

The checkbox is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="confirm" class="confirm">
```

The button is:

```
<form action="resetprocess.php" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" id="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset <i class="icon-repeat"></i></button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to capture the click event of your button and then check whether the checkbox is clicked or not. If not, you can send the alert and return false (be sure to do this otherwise the form will be submitted anyway).

```
$('#reset').click(function () {
    if (!$('#confirm').is(':checked')) {
        alert('not checked');
        return false;
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dvTXV/)**

Comment: Your return was the thing that was missing, i thank you great sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#reset").on('click',function(){
  if(!$("#confirm").is(':checked')){
   // alert("");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
    if ($("#checkbox:checked").length == 0)
        alert("Checkbox not checked!");
});
```