# Display alert if checkbox IS checked on button click

Tags: javascript

How do I achieve the opposite of this case?

[Display alert if checkbox isn't checked on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046953/display-alert-if-checkbox-isnt-checked-on-button-click)

Comment: There's a magic operator in that solution "!" - try removing it.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript

Comment: @MBottens 2 worst sites you could suggest for learning JS

Comment: Maybe you should share then ;) I've never done either, I mostly learned by branching away from jquery

Comment: Thank You!!! Yuriy Galanter @yuriy-galanter